# Handling "Error: No Recipients Defined" in "Trigger Email from Firestore" extension

Tags: email, google-cloud-firestore, triggers

I am able to trigger email messages well enough when I put my email address in the "to" field of a new document of my "mail" collection.

But I don't like programming my web page so that everyone can see this email address.

It seems like this extension has a great solution. I just need to configure the "Users collection" in the extension settings. But it is hard to get the details right.

Here is what I am doing...

1. Create a new email/password user and copy the UID for it.
2. Create a "sendgrid_users" collection and make a document in there
   with doc-id copied from first step.
3. Reconfigure the extension so that "sendgrid_users" is the "Users collection"
4. Create a new document in the "mail" collection and instead of
   writing my email address in the "to" field, I put the UID in there.

As I said, all works if I put an email address in the "to" field, but using the UID leads to the error "Error: No recipients defined".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a few things about making this work.

Most importantly, switch from using the "to" attribute (which works with an email address) to using the "toUids" attribute (which works with the "users" collection specified in extension config)

The "toUids" attribute needs to contain an array of document ids that can be used to find a documents in your users collection. Then the email addresses will be inferred by "email" attributes on those documents.

By the way, there is no need for step 1. All can be done in firestore without touching your authentication config at all. We are really just needed a lookup table for email addresses.